# Renaming worksheets by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename workbook sheets with VBA in a loop with if-clauses.

Copied sheets show up with the title "TEMPLATE (i)" for i = 1...38, instead of being renamed with an incrementing index value.

```vb
Sub dataExtraction()

Dim user_state As Integer
Dim index As Integer
Dim nums As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

Dim status As String
Dim billingMethod As String
 
status = "inaktiv"
billingMethod = "Projektverrechnung"
x = 1

For i = 2 To 500

    If Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then index = index + 1 Else
    If Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) Else
    
    Worksheets("TEMPLATE (2)").Activate
    
    If Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then Sheets("TEMPLATE (2)").Name = index Else
    
    Worksheets("dataset").Activate
            
Next i
    
MsgBox (index)
MsgBox "The name of the active sheet is " & ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are not qualifying the Range (`Cells(i, 13)`). Qualifying means that you tell VBA from which sheet you want to read. If you omit this, always the active sheet is used.

Now you check for `If Cells(i, 13).Value = status` multiple time. However, after copying the template sheet, the active sheet changed to the new created sheet and therefore the last If-statement fails (because now the `Cells(i, 13)` is read from that sheet).

Some more remarks to your code:

Your usage of the If-statement is sub-optimal. Don't repeat the same check multiple times, but instead use the syntax shown below, using `End If`.

As said, after copying a sheet, the new sheet is already active, no need to activate it again. This will especially fail when a sheet `"TEMPLATE (2)"` already exists because the new created sheet will be for example `"TEMPLATE (3)"` and you rename the wrong sheet

One minor thing: Make it a habit to use `Long` instead of `Integer`, especially when dealing with row numbers. This avoids numeric overflow errors.

Your code could look like this. Note that I am using a `With`-statement and qualify `.Cells(i, 13)` by putting a dot at the beginning. This ensures that the cell is always red from the dataset sheet, no matter which sheet is currently active.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dataset")
    For i = 2 To 500
        If .Cells(i, 13).Value = Status Then
            Index = Index + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
            ActiveSheet.Name = Index
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Solid approach - really appreciate that! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `dataset` sheet contains the values `inaktiv`. In this case after activating the `TEMPLATE (2)` sheet it is necessary to qualifying the cells(i, 13).

```
For i = 2 To 500

    If Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then index = index + 1 Else
    If Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) Else
    
    Worksheets("TEMPLATE (2)").Activate
    
    If Worksheets("dataset").Cells(i, 13).Value = status Then Sheets("TEMPLATE (2)").Name = index Else    ' modification
    
    Worksheets("dataset").Activate
            
Next i
```